# How to fix "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post" WordPress error?

Tags: wordpress

I have a standard WordPress blog. I already created about 10 articles there, uploaded pictures and did everything the same as other WordPress users. Two months later, I wanted to add another article. I did it manually in the panel, but when I clicked on the “Save draft” button, I got the error "Updating error. Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this entry.”. Of course, I googled and tried to fix the error based on the information I found. I tried many things, but nothing helped. What could be causing this problem?

Additional Info: WordPress is behaving strangely. It gives the error "WordPress auto-update failed - please try again." There is still enough free space on the server. I made access rights to all folders with the code 777. Not a single plugin works. The theme has nothing to do with it.